# Which chapter should I continue after the anime's ending: Yuki and Kaname leaving Cross Academy?

Tags: vampire-knight

After watching the anime, I was curious about the story after that.

Which chapter of the *Vampire Knight* manga should I read after Yuki and Kaname left Cross Academy?